# Resolving ties in MySQL rankings

Tags: mysql, ranking

I have a MySQL table that looks something like this:

```
GOALS
------------------------
   PLAYER   |   GOALS
------------------------
     001    |    30
     002    |    25
     003    |    25
     004    |    20
```

I want to have a rank-based scoring system that gives half-points for ties. In the above example, it should look like this:

```
GOALS
-----------------------------------
   PLAYER   |   GOALS   |   SCORE
-----------------------------------
     001    |    30     |    4
     002    |    25     |    2.5
     003    |    25     |    2.5
     004    |    20     |    1
```

In case of a three-way tie:

```
GOALS
-----------------------------------
   PLAYER   |   GOALS   |   SCORE
-----------------------------------
     001    |    30     |    5
     002    |    25     |    3
     003    |    25     |    3
     004    |    25     |    3
     005    |    20     |    1
```

How would something like this be done in mySQL?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for pure MySQL answer or can other languages operating with MySQL be used such as PHP?

Comment: I'm using Node.js for my application, so that would be nice, too. I'm guessing you mean to iterate through the sorted goals list and add points to each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a.player, a.goals, (SUM(a.goals > b.goals) + 1 + SUM(a.goals >= b.goals))/2 AS score
FROM goals a
CROSS JOIN goals b
GROUP BY player
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/26cd9/3)

This works because `SUM(a.goals > b.goals) + 1` is the minimum rank of all the tied players, while `SUM(a.goals >= b.goals)` is the maximum rank. So this averages the two ends of the range to get the score.

Comment: Well, this appears to be verging on genius.